# Inserting a value into all rows in the column in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

[image: Table]

I wanted to overwrite all the values in the `Project1` column with `0`. Is there a way to do this ? Like all the students in `studentid` will all have `0` values in `Project1`.

Comment: Update tabelName set Project1 = 0 Use this

Comment: There are quite a few ways actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use an [update query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

For your example:

```
UPDATE `TABLE_NAME` SET `Project1` = 0
```

Comment: did you think of what that will do here to their db?

Comment: overwrite *all* their Project1 values. Exactly what he wants to

Answer (score 0):

DO :

```
UPDATE table_name SET Project1=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just omit where clause in Mysql, run this

```
update `mytable` set
`Project1` = 0
;
```